# Radio button list on Android

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences, preference, listpreference

I want to have a list with radio buttons displayed when a Preference in a PreferenceActivity is selected(like when the Music preference is selected on an HTC sensation in the default gallery app-slideshow).
I do not want to use fragments because the above model was running Gingerbread and doesn't support fragments.
The list should also have buttons at the bottom. It's a sort of ListPreference. But, like a customized ListPreference(so that it has more than the default single button and also the list occupies the entire screen)
So, how do you display a list like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as the TextView for the list items:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radio_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingRight="3dip"
    android:padding="10dip"    
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Comment: This part is not visible, don't know why:   
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:id="@+id/radio_text_view" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="3dip" android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle" android:paddingRight="3dip" android:padding="10dip" android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" />

Answer (score 0):

for list preferences with radio button use this

```
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/scheme_choices"
    android:entryValues="@array/scheme_values"
    android:key="scheme"
    android:title="Scheme" />
```

add required values in the string.xml file

```
<string-array name="scheme_values">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
</string-array>
```

values

```
<string-array name="scheme_choices">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want a ListPreference. I want to use Preference.A Preference that when clicked would result in a ListPreference of sorts being displayed.

Comment: Yes. I know what a ListPreference is and I don't want to use it. Do you know how to display a List of radio buttons on click of Preference? SHould it be done in Preference.OnClickListener?